# How to use main query column value in sub-query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an SQL query where I want to use one of the column value of the main query in the sub query.

The query is:

```
select **tool.item**, asset.id, tool.date,
       (select freq from workorder
        where type = 'CP' and itemnum = **tool.item**) freq, asset.pm
from tool,
     asset
where too.num = asset.num 
  and asset.status = 'ACTIVE';
```

In this query I want use the fetched tool.item value  in the sub query.

```
item assetid date       pm   freq

A1    1      12-NOV-15  123  freq from workorder where itemnum ='A1'
A2    2      13-NOV-15  124  freq from workorder where itemnum ='A2'
```

Could you help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a join on workorder?

Comment: are you sure you need a subquery here?  How many workorder records per toolitem do you expect?  If there is only 1 then a simple join is fine

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to do two things:

- Learn proper `JOIN` syntax (*never* use commas in the `from` clause.
- Use abbreviations for table aliases.

So, write the query as:

```
select t.item, a.id, t.date,
       (select wo.freq
        from workorder wo
        where wo.type = 'CP' and wo.itemnum = t.item
       ) as freq, 
       a.pm
from tool t join
     asset a
     on t.num = a.num 
where a.status = 'ACTIVE';
```

A correlated subquery is a query where the subquery uses columns from the outer query.  In this case, the correlation uses `t.item` in the `where` clause.  When using correlated subqueries I very, very, very strongly recommend that you always use table aliases.  It is very easy to make mistakes with column names, and these problems can be quite hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

it's similar to normal `join`, you need join you subquery in column with your tables in `from` section
if the query returns null or 1 value it works ok
if it returns more than 1 value you will have exception

```
select tool.item, asset.id, tool.date,
       (select freq from workorder
        where type = 'CP' and itemnum = tool.item) freq, asset.pm
from tool,
     asset
where tool.num = asset.num 
  and asset.status = 'ACTIVE';
```